# Reading/writing apache feather files from a compiled python script fails

Tags: python, pyinstaller, py2exe, auto-py-to-exe, feather

I'm trying to create a script that converts a csv file to a feather file, then compile that script
to a stand-alone exe which can be invoked from other applications supplying two parameters - path to a csv file and a path to the output feather file. Environment is Windows 10, Python 311.
I've created, and successfully run, a script that does what's required when invoked from the command line like:

> python arraowreadfeather.py  C:\temp\Feather_test\data.csv  C:\temp\Feather_test\data.feather

I've compiled the script to an exe using three tools freely available - py2exe, pyinstaller and auto-py-to-exe.

However, when I compile this script to an exe - either stand-alone or in a single folder - then run it from the command line I get this error:

> C:\temp\csvtofeather\dist>arrowreadfeather.exe C:\temp\Feather_test\data.feather
> Calling from_feather with:  C:\temp\Feather_test\data.feather
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "arrowreadfeather.py", line 28, in <module>
> File "arrowreadfeather.py", line 22, in main
> File "arrowreadfeather.py", line 7, in from_feather
> File "pyarrow\feather.pyc", line 226, in read_feather
> File "pyarrow\array.pxi", line 830, in pyarrow.lib._PandasConvertible.to_pandas
> File "pyarrow\table.pxi", line 3990, in pyarrow.lib.Table._to_pandas
> File "pyarrow\pandas_compat.pyc", line 810, in table_to_blockmanager
> File "pyarrow\pandas_compat.pyc", line 968, in _reconstruct_index
> File "pyarrow\pandas-shim.pxi", line 126, in pyarrow.lib._PandasAPIShim.pd.**get**
> File "pyarrow\pandas-shim.pxi", line 100, in pyarrow.lib._PandasAPIShim._check_import
> File "pyarrow\pandas-shim.pxi", line 56, in pyarrow.lib._PandasAPIShim._import_pandas
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyarrow.vendored.version'

I simplified the script just to read an existing feather file and that gives the same error.
Here is the simplified script and the error output:

```
`import sys
import pyarrow.feather as ft

def from_feather(_file: str):
    table = ft.read_feather(_file)
    return table

def main():
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print("Insufficient args for conversion. Specify a source and dest.")
        return None
        
    print("Calling from_feather with: ",sys.argv[1])
    feather_file = sys.argv[1]
    d_table = from_feather(feather_file)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()`
```

> C:\Python311\output>arrowreadfeather.exe C:\temp\Feather_test\data.feather
> Calling from_feather with:  C:\temp\Feather_test\data.feather
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "arrowreadfeather.py", line 23, in 
> File "arrowreadfeather.py", line 19, in main
> File "arrowreadfeather.py", line 5, in from_feather
> File "pyarrow\feather.py", line 226, in read_feather
> File "pyarrow\array.pxi", line 830, in pyarrow.lib._PandasConvertible.to_pandas
> File "pyarrow\table.pxi", line 3990, in pyarrow.lib.Table._to_pandas
> File "pyarrow\pandas_compat.py", line 810, in table_to_blockmanager
> File "pyarrow\pandas_compat.py", line 968, in _reconstruct_index
> File "pyarrow\pandas-shim.pxi", line 126, in pyarrow.lib._PandasAPIShim.pd.**get**
> File "pyarrow\pandas-shim.pxi", line 100, in pyarrow.lib._PandasAPIShim._check_import
> File "pyarrow\pandas-shim.pxi", line 56, in pyarrow.lib._PandasAPIShim._import_pandas
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyarrow.vendored.version'
> [20312] Failed to execute script 'arrowreadfeather' due to unhandled exception!

Thanks in advance for any help/pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The information above did solve my problem. Steps taken.

1. Create a .spec file from the script you want to convert to an exe using this command:

   pyi-makespec --onefile yourscriptfile.py

This creates a .spec file that pyinstaller uses to create the stand-alone exe.

2. Edit the .spec file in a text editor. In my case I added the following details required to solve my issue:

   from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_submodules
   allhiddenimports = collect_submodules('pyarrow.vendored')
3. Edit the field 'hiddenimports' to read as follows:

   hiddenimports=allhiddenimports,
4. Build the script using the .spec file with the following command:
   pyinstaller yourspecfile.spec

This did indeed produce an executable that runs without dependency issues.

I don't work on Python that often and needed both those pieces of info. above to get to a working solution. I would like to give joint kudos but...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a file named hook-pyarrow.py
and then put this code into it

```py
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_submodules

hiddenimports = collect_submodules('pyarrow.vendored')
```

Comment: I don't thing it will entirely solve the problem

Comment: Please note: I'm not a professional python dev.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If I create the file you've mentioned above how/where do I use it in the build process?

Comment: The code he's posted would usually be put in a 'build.spec' config file that will then set the parameters when you run Pyinstaller. From what I can see, his suggestion will work if you implement the '.spec' file properly. Just pass the 'hiddenimports' variable above to the 'hidden_imports' parameter of the Analysis class (for reference: https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/spec-files.html#:~:text=The%20spec%20file%20tells%20PyInstaller,contents%20of%20the%20spec%20file.)